# iframe not centered horizontally

Tags: css, html, iframe, center

Trying to center iframe horizontally and it doesn't seem to work

css:

```
div.center iframe {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="center">

<iframe class="paraviewweb-player" type="text/html"
        width="401px" height="401px" frameborder="0"
        style="border: 1px solid;"
        src="embed.html">
</iframe>

</div>
```

Comment: You don't need to use the wrapper div, your code works for me though: http://jsfiddle.net/qL9PV/

Comment: This will work fine in this isolated example, you have another problem.

Comment: Can you show us the CSS code for your div.center? Probably you used a fixed width for it or something like that? The iframe in your example is only centered within the parent (div.center)...

Comment: Thanks to all for help. I discovered it was not picking up my css code. Fixed the path to css file and everything is working as it should